# Is it bad practice to change the working directory to import from different files?

Tags: python, python-import, relative-import

Relative imports do not work in interactive python sessions, but I could change the directory `os.chdir('..')` then `import module_in_parent` and then go back `os.chdir('original_directory')`. Or do the same for a parallel directory.

Would that be considered bad practice, and if so, why? (I haven't really seen it used, but ran into the problem multiple times myself.)

I have used some scripts and utility functions for an experiment and would like to keep the folder-structure as is, but also reuse some of the scripts for a new experiment.

Edit: Here is an example with a folder structure:

```bash
project/
├── experiment
│   ├── main.py
│   └── utils
│       └── utils_functions.py
└── new_experiment
    └── main2_.py
```

Where I want to import `utils_functions` from main2.py. And I don't want to change anything in `experiment`.

@Random Davis: In the example above, I get the error `ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` with importlib.

I am not working on a program with a single entry point, but rather doing some data analysis, where I use multiple short scripts to modify and visualize the data.

Comment: It seems like `importlib` would do what you want: `module = importlib.import_module('folder_name.module_name')`. Changing the working directory could be error-prone since you have to remember to change it back, and it would just look odd.

Comment: **Yes**, it's bad practice. Just add every path you need to `sys.path` (but if you're doing it right, you shouldn't need to do this at all for `..`, because something in _its_ parent should _already_ be in `sys.path`). That is, if your current module is `foo.bar.baz` (`src/foo/bar/baz.py`) and you want to import `foo.qux` (`src/foo/qux.py`), you should just `import foo.qux`, not `import qux` from `..`

Comment: In general, running `os.chdir()` is a side effect, and having side effects of importing modules is bad juju.

Comment: You should be packaging and installing your projects so that the working directory doesn't matter. The fundamental problem is relying on the working directory being in the import path. That is a convenience for working on simple scripts. But once you get to the point where *toy care about s whole project structure* then you should package and install

Comment: Anything related to import magic is a bad practice, but... Ask yourself, if keeping directory structure worth of having hard to read/maintain/explain code. If yes, I personally don't see why you should not use such import trick. I had a project with requirement to keep code in folders with non-valid python package names, and import system was hacked here as well. It worked fine for years, and there were 0 complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy enough to add your directories to the search path - actually, I think it is easier than changing the directory.

While changing the directoy in this way would be very, very, very bad in a running program, in an interactive session it is just cumbersome - so, ok, you did it once, it did what you needed, you did that twice - fine...but repeating it over and over is just a no.

The directories where Python look for files to import is a plain list of strings, and it is trivial to add the directories you want there, in the priority order you want:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path; import os, sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(os.getcwd()).parent())
```

will insert the parent dir in the Python path for import. without changing the working directory. (It can be removed from the list, afterwards, as well). Also, the `pathlib.Path` juggling is just to be able to use `.parent` - one could just do `sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + "/..")` - (and the `insert(0, ...)` is just the insert method of regular lists, putting the new path at the position 0)